# Call Service from Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to call a service from a Spring Bean:

```
  private Encryption encryption;

  @Autowired
  public ReportingController(ReportingService reportingService, Encryption encryption) {
    this.reportingService = reportingService;
    this.encryption = encryption;
  }
```

Interface:

```
public interface Encryption {

  String encryptionContent(String contentType, String content);

  Map<String, List<String>> encryptionHeaders(Map<String, List<String>> headers);

}

class EncryptionImpl implements Encryption {

  .....
  EncryptionImpl(List<ContentEncryption> enc, HeaderEncryption headerEncryption) {
    this.enc = enc;
    this.headerEncryption = headerEncryption;
  }
}
```

Bean:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(EncryptionProperties.class)
public class EncryptionConfiguration {

  @Bean
  HeaderEncryption headerEncryption(EncryptionProperties encryptionProperties) {
    return new HeaderEncryption(encryptionProperties);
  }

  @Bean
  Encryption intEncryption(List<ContentEncryption> enc, HeaderEncryption headerEncryption) {
    return new EncryptionImpl(enc, headerEncryption);
  }

}
```

But when I deploy the code I get error:

```
Parameter 1 of constructor in com.test.utils.admin.web.rest.controller.ReportingController required a bean of type 'com.security.logging.encryption.Encryption' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.security.logging.encryption.Encryption' in your configuration.
```

As you can see I have a definition for a Bean but I try also to inject it and use it as a service?

How I can implement this properly?

For code example: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Generic_SO_POC/tree/master/src/main/java/com

Comment: Does `EncryptionConfiguration` also have an `@Configuration` annotation you're not showing?

Comment: No, only this code.

Comment: So you _don't_ have a bean because EncryptionConfiguration isn't actually a loaded configuration?

Comment: hm... I'm not sure. I suppose that the beans are created but I'm not accessing  them properly.

Comment: They're not created if that file is not a configuration, regardless of what you've named the class. Unless there's somewhere else where you're loading it as a configuration directly instead of relying on the component scan... You need `@Configuration` for it to be picked up by the component scan.

Comment: I will look into your code and try to provide detailed explanation.